# Вопрос по Java Web

Tags: java, веб-программирование, jsp, jstl

кто может подсказать, нашёл такой код(отрывок):

```
public class ListBean {
   public List<String> getItems() {
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       list.add("Thing1");
       list.add("Thing2");
       list.add("Thing3");
       return list;
   }
 }
```

чтобы полученный список отобразить на странице JSP, используется такой код(часть кода):

```
<jsp:useBean id="obj" class="com.example.ListBean" scope="page"/>
<select>
    <c:forEach var="item" items="${obj.items}">
     <option>${item}</option>
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

Вопрос - как мы получаем значение `items="${obj.items}"`. Как я понял, из функции public `List<String> getItems()`, но почему именно такое название у ф-ии? (именно get и название с большой буквы(в моём случае `Items`))

Comment: `getItems` - по правилам `code style` в джаве. Параметр берется не из метода, а до отображения страницы где-то в коде положили атрибут для страницы с именем `obj` у которого значение результат выполнения метода `getitems`.  Если просто то это `JSTL` библиотека.

Comment: Требования к именованию методов закреплены в [спецификации JavaBeans](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html).

Comment: спасибо большое всем ответившим! разобрался в вопросе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы используете выражение `EL` в JSTL.  То есть строка выражения `obj.items` передается движку выражений и точка `.` в этом языке означает доступ к свойству объекта.

Каким способом можно получить доступ к свойству зависит от реализации движка, обычно используются геттеры, которые в [JavaBeans](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) спецификации имеют методы с префиксом `get` и именем свойства с большой буквы.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ!